# MVC 6 link tag helpers not creating proper URL

Tags: asp.net-mvc, tag-helpers

I have an MVC 6 project that has routing set up as:

```
app.UseMvc(routes =>
            {
                routes.MapRoute(
                    name: "default",
                    template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}/{closeOnSubmit?}");
            });
```

I'm attempting to build a hyperlink using tag helpers like:

```
<a asp-controller="MyController" asp-action="Create" asp-route-closeOnSubmit="true" class="fa fa-plus indent-15">+</a>
```

When the page is created and I mouse over the link, it's reporting as `http://localhost/MyController/Create` without the closeOnSubmit parameter.  When I examine the HTML in Chrome's developer tools, it looks like:

```
<a href class="fa fa-plus indent-15">+</a>
```

What do I need to do to get the closeOnSubmit parameter to be properly appended to the route?

Edit:
I don't fully understand MVC routing, so unfortunately gave some erroneous information.  When I first created my app, it had the default route of:

```
app.UseMvc(routes =>
            {
                routes.MapRoute(
                    name: "default",
                    template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
            });
```

When trying to get this working, I thought that maybe it wasn't routing correctly because I didn't have closeOnSubmit added into the route.  After reading Darin's answer, I understand it and definitely had it wrong after adding it to the route.  However, for this particular route, I don't need an id passed.  I tried changing the default route so that it used closeOnSubmit rather than id and it still didn't fix the issue of links not being created correctly.

While troubleshooting, I also found that the routes are even more wrong than I thought.  The page I am working on is generated by going to `http://localhost/ControllerOne/Create`.  The page that the hyperlink should point to is `http://localhost/ControllerTwo/Create'.  Even though my asp-controller tag is set to ControllerTwo, all of my hyperlinks are showing as`http://ControllerOne/Create`.  I have a feeling that that's just because of the empty href attribute, but I'd like to know what's causing the href attribute to be empty.

Answer (score 0):

Only the last parameter of a route can be optional. Otherwise the routing engine simply cannot disambiguate your routes.

Think about it, when the routing engine encounters this url:

```
http://localhost/MyController/Create/true
```

does the `true` token should be bound to the `id` parameter or the `closeOnSubmit` parameter?

So make sure that your `id` parameter is mandatory:

```
template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id}/{closeOnSubmit?}"
```

and that you have specified a value for it when building your url:

```
<a asp-controller="MyController" asp-action="Create" asp-route-id="1234" asp-route-closeOnSubmit="true" class="fa fa-plus indent-15">+</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Wow, PEBKAC.

The problem came in because the controller I was referencing didn't exist yet.  Which, IIRC, would cause an error in MVC5 rather than creating an empty HREF tag.  Either way I should have been smart enough to see that one.